# New user - couldn't capable of commenting but can post answer

Tags: discussion

Particular to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115875/is-home-not-working-in-functions-php-file) thread, new user [Manish](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/37569/manish) couldn't comment due to his low reputation, but he had something to say about the question. So he posted an Answer like a comment.

**Moderation:** Generically the Answer is to be flagged as "Not Answer". But to the scenario and the situation, the comment-like Answer was necessary. What should we people do then? We know it's not an Answer.

Do we vote for a poll saying **Open commenting to all reputed user**?
Or, Do we add a comment *on behalf* of the New User?

Answer (score 6):

Flag it as **Not an answer**, and a moderator will decide if the answer should be converted to a comment.